# What is the Regular expression for multiple word combinations

Tags: regex, shell

Can some one help me to find a regular expression for the pattern below,

I am trying to use regular expression to match a patter in shell script.

The pattern could be a combination of 'ab' 'xy' 'ij' 'pqr', in any order and seperated by a comma ',' or only 'all'

Ex.

```
1) "ab,xy,ij,pqr" - valid

2) "ij,pqr" - valid

3) "all" - valid

4) "ij,ab," - invalid because it ends with a comma

5) "all,xy" - invalid because 'all' cannot be combined with xy ij pqr or ab

6) ",xy" - invalid because it starts with comma

7) "xy" - valid
```

Thank you.

@konsolebox @491243 @ajp15243 @Jerry
Looks like I am doing something wrong, it works only for the RE regex4="(ab|xy|ij|pqr)(,(ab|xy|ij|pqr))*" so far and that too only if the string is like "ab,xy" just "ab" doesn't work.
Here is what I have attempted so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

echo
echo echo $1
echo

regex2="^(all|(ab|xy|ij|pqr)(,(ab|xy|ij|pqr))*)$"
regex3="^(all|(ab|xy|ij|pqr)(,(ab|xy|ij|pqr))*)$"
regex4="(ab|xy|ij|pqr)(,(ab|xy|ij|pqr))*"

if [[ $1 == $regex2 ]]
then
  echo "You got it again 22222222 !"
fi

if [[ $1 == $regex3 ]]
then
  echo "You got it again 33333333 !"
fi

if [[ $1 == $regex4 ]]
then
  echo "You got it again 44444444 !"
fi
```

Output:

```
$
$ test.ksh ab,xy

echo ab,xy

You got it again 44444444 !
$
$
$
$ test.ksh ab

echo ab

$
```

1:30 PST

Ok, had some improvement:

```
"((ab|xy|ij|pqr)|(ab|xy|ij|pqr)(,(ab|xy|ij|pqr))*)|all)$"
```

this one works when the input is "xy", "xy,ab" but it also treating "xy,ab,all" as valid input.

Comment: Do you have any attempts?

Comment: What do you mean by attempts?

Comment: I am trying to match this pattern in a shell script if condition.

Comment: Attempts as in what have you been trying so far.

Comment: Have you written any code that attempts to solve for what you're asking? If so, edit it into your question please. As it is, your question boils down to "here are my requirements, what's the solution"? There may be a lot of (old or new) SO questions of this format, but a good question on SO generally has the author's code attempts. If nothing else, it encourages the current types of answers: those with code but no explanation. If you don't know a decent amount about regexes, the current answers are a bit dense.

Comment: I am sorry for the delay.

Comment: so both the expressions below ^(((ab|xy|ij|pqr)(,(ab|xy|ij|pqr))*)|all)$ and ^(all|(ab|xy|ij|pqr)(,(ab|xy|ij|pqr))*)$ are not working, but if I remove teh starting ^ and ending $ and also remove '| all', it is working for xy,ab etc ... but again it doesn't work for only xy or ab, I will copy paste my script, looks like I am doing something wrong while comparing.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do it.

```
^(((ab|xy|ij|pqr)(,(ab|xy|ij|pqr))*)|all)$
```

- [Screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29622718/regex3.JPG)

Comment: Thank you, please look at my output after the question.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this:

```
^(all|(ab|xy|ij|pqr)(,(ab|xy|ij|pqr))*)$
```

Comment: Thank you, please look at my output after the question.

Comment: @Cosmic I think you need to use `=~` instead of `==`.

Comment: @Cosmic In my version of ksh it doesn't. What version of ksh are you using? Perhaps you could just use grep? `if echo "$1" | grep "$regex" > /dev/null`

Comment: I don't know that version of ksh, none of the the commands are working (echo $KSH_VERSION, ${.sh.version}). What does > /dev/null do?

Comment: @Cosmic It redirects output of grep to nothing (/dev/null). The only purpose of the `if` command is to let grep check the string if it's valid based on an expression.

Answer (score 0):

ok, looks like finially the below RE worked, thank you all for the help.

```
(all)|(ab|xy|ij|pqr)|(ab|xy|ij|pqr)(,(ab|xy|ij|pqr)*)
```